# Rendering Problems: java.lang.NullPointerException at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView in Android Studio 1.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I have recently updated android sdk to api 22 and android studio 1.1.0. After that I am getting rendering issues on RecyclerView. Here is what I am getting

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1216)
at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15237)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:2440)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1086)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
```

> I am getting this exception on xml preview/design, so I am not able to
>   view the xml design.

The project is working fine without any exception.
Here is my widget

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:fadeScrollbars="false"
            />
```

This is my code

```
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
    layoutManager=new GridLayoutManager(this,2);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: post your code,  not just layout xml

Comment: same problem for me and SOLVED!  
I found this error related to following three: 1, make sure library "com.android.support:appcompat" and "com.android.support:recyclerview" are save version; 2，remove property "android:scrollbars"; 3，add layoutmanager to recycleview in ur code

Comment: yes. removing android:scrollbars solved my problem

Answer (score 31, accepted):

My problem was solved when I took out this line from the xml file for the RecyclerView:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

EDIT: The root of this issue was pointed out by commentators on this solution - to solve the problem, you can just ensure that the LayoutManager for the RecyclerView is set before you display the RecyclerView with the scrollbars property set.

Comment: I found this error related to following three: 1, make sure library "com.android.support:appcompat" and "com.android.support:recyclerview" are save version; 2，remove property "android:scrollbars"; 3，add layoutmanager to recycleview in ur code

Comment: this isn't a real solution. Removing something that the developer wants to be there just for the sake of not crashing is never a solution. This error happens because the recyclerview is showing but no layout manager is set.

Comment: @androidpotato7 your solution solved it, and you have a point in saying what you said!

Answer (score 11):

You just forgot to set a LayoutManager:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.LayoutManager)

Comment: I already set it. Currently I am working by changing the preview version to api 21

Comment: @n1m1 you didn't set it correctly or in the right place. Check your code, the solution you accepted is no solution.

Answer (score 6):

I have had the same error. line 1216 of RecyclerView is:

```
return mLayout.canScrollVertically() ? mLayout.computeVerticalScrollRange(mState) : 0;
```

mLayout being null at the time is the issue, I am not sure why it is null, but it appears you have to call setLayoutManager() on your RecyclerView immediately after `setContentView()` or `inflate()`. My code was running a background thread before I tried to access the RecyclerView and call its `setLayoutManager()`. Once I changed to the following, it works

i.e.

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.schedule);
rv = (RecyclerView) this.findViewById(R.id.schedule_listview);
rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

I am still not quite understand why have to do that though

Answer (score 5):

You dont need to remove any line, but to add the following line to your code:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.getContext()));
```

This way, there is no problem for the Vertical scrolling on the RecyclerView.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case people are still wondering, you should update to the latest SDK platform for API 22 via the SDK Manager, and update to the latest recycler view by updating the Support repository via the SDK Manager, and in your `build.gradle` file to use the latest version (22.0.0)

Answer (score 0):

i just removed the property android:scrollbars="vertical" and everything will be fine