# RecyclerView Endless Infinite Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview, infinite-scroll, endlessscroll

I am trying to implement Endless Infinite Scrolling with RecyclerView, but I am only getting first 10 records, not getting next 10 records and even not getting any progress while trying to scroll at bottom.

**Whereas I was suppose to get next 10 records on scroll and so on... But getting only first 10 records**

Here I have uploaded [copy](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r8cu9lc3x01l4rj/mytest.txt?dl=0) of my JSON - But i am not able to fetch data from same url, that's why i am using client's url and local host.

I am following [this](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/06/endless-recyclerview-with-progress-bar.html) tutorial

Here is my complete code, May I know where I am doing mistake ?

**JSON :**

```
{
  "names": [
    {
      "name": "Name 1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Name 2"
    },
    ....
    {
      "name": "Name 60"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Log:**

```
D/name -(13759): Name 1
D/name -(13759): Name 2
.......................
D/name -(13759): Name 60
```

Here is my updated code, which i am using to parse JSON data

**MainActivity.java: UPDATED**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;

private TextView tvEmptyView;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private DataAdapter mAdapter;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

private ArrayList<Student> studentList;

protected Handler handler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    tvEmptyView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

    studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();

    handler = new Handler();
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Android Students");
    }

    loadData();

}

// load initial data
private void loadData() {       
    new Parser().execute("http://10.0.2.2/jsons/mytest.txt");               
}

class Parser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        dialog.show();
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            //------------------>>
            HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet(urls[0]);
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            // StatusLine stat = response.getStatusLine();
            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if (status == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

                JSONObject jsono = new JSONObject(data);
                JSONArray jarray = jsono.getJSONArray("names");

                for (int i = 0; i < jarray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject object = jarray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Student actor = new Student();

                    actor.setName(object.getString("name"));
                    Log.d("name - ", object.getString("name"));

                    studentList.add(actor);             
                }

                Log.d("MainActivity:StudentList ", "The size "+studentList.size());                 

                return true;
            }

            //------------------>>

        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();

        Log.d("MainActivity:StudentList ", "The size "+studentList.size());

        ArrayList< Student > temArray = 
                 new ArrayList< Student >(studentList.subList(0, 10));           
        mAdapter = new DataAdapter(temArray, mRecyclerView);

        Log.d("MainActivity:TempList ", "The size "+temArray.size());

        // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);     
        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        if (studentList.isEmpty()) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                studentList.add(null);
                mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size() - 1);

                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //   remove progress item
                        studentList.remove(studentList.size() - 1);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(studentList.size());
                        //add items one by one
                        int start = studentList.size();
                        int end = start + 10;

                        for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
                            mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
                        }
                        mAdapter.setLoaded();
                       //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    }
}

}
```

**DataAdapter.java:**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    private List<Student> studentList;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public DataAdapter(List<Student> students, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        studentList = students;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();


                    recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return studentList.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
            int viewType) {
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

            vh = new StudentViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progress_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder instanceof StudentViewHolder) {

            Student singleStudent= (Student) studentList.get(position);

            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).tvName.setText(singleStudent.getName());

            ((StudentViewHolder) holder).student= singleStudent;

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentList.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }


    //
    public static class StudentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView tvName;     

        public Student student;

        public StudentViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            tvName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvName);

            v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),
                            "OnClick :" + student.getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ProgressBar progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar) v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        }
    }
}
```

**OnLoadMoreListener.java:**

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
     void onLoadMore();
}
```

Comment: can you execute http://10.0.2.2/jsons/mytest.txt in browser and see what are you getting there ?

Comment: can you log `data` in `LogCat` and see what it prints ?

Comment: you are not adding items in loop inside loadMore

Comment: since you are loading all items at once i think you will not need load more. You have not changed visibility of list view on post execute.  add `if (studentList.isEmpty()) {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            mRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tvEmptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }` on post execute of async task

Comment: Getting first 11 black item due to `for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            studentList.add(new Student());
        }` please remove these lines

Comment: @Oreo: see my answer probably help u

Comment: Have you seen the code at https://github.com/weixiao1984/Android-Infinite-Scroll-Listview ?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue once an I solve it using this code ...
First .. create this class

```
public abstract class EndlessOnScrollListener extends OnScrollListener {

    public static String TAG = EndlessOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    // use your LayoutManager instead
    private LinearLayoutManager llm;

    public EndlessOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager sglm) {
        this.lm = llm;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
            onScrolledToEnd();
        }
    }

    public abstract void onScrolledToEnd();
}
```

Second .. in you activity use this

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessOnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolledToEnd() {
        if (!loading) {
            loading = true;
            // add 10 by 10 to tempList then notify changing in data
        }
        loading = false;
    }
});
```

This works for me .... I hope it works for you to.

Answer (score 1):

Try notifyItemRangeChanged

```
yourCurrentList.addAll(newData);    
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(yourCurretList.size() + 1, newDataSize);
```

I think this'll  help you.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
private List<Student> studentList;
```

with

```
private List<Object> list;
```

also replace

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return studentList.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}
```

with

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return list.get(position) instanceof Student ?  VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
}
```

for detect end of List you can using

```
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            // When went to the end of the list, load more posts
            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

                if (linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition() >= linearLayoutManager.getItemCount() - 1) {

                    // Grow List
                }
            }
}
```

Also for Add Loading Item. add this code in adapter

```
public void addLoadingView(){
   list.add(new Object());
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.**

> Getting first 11 recyclerview Items blank (And showing progress bar
>   continuously), see below screenshot:

Change `loadData` method as:

```
private void loadData() {
  new Parser().execute("http://clienturl.com/jsons/mytest.txt");  
 }
```

**2.**

> Whereas I was suppose to get first 10 records, and on scroll next 10
>   records and so on...

Change `onPostExecute` method of `Parser` as:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
    dialog.cancel();
    ArrayList< Student > temArray = 
                 new ArrayList< Student >(studentList.subList(0, 10));           
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(temArray, mRecyclerView);

    // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
 }
```

And also remove following lines from `onCreate` method:

```
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(studentList, mRecyclerView);

    // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: @Oreo: ok move `mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener` method code inside onPostExecute after `mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` line

Comment: @Oreo: Fixed or still facing same issue?

Comment: @Oreo: getting data in `studentList` ? use log and check both `studentList` and `temArray` ArrayList Size

Comment: @Oreo: please add debugger in `onPostExecute` method and check it is executing or not?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91808/discussion-between--k-and-oreo).

Comment: @Oreo: please check following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29005644/rendering-problems-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-android-support-v7-widget

Comment: bhaiya answer mat do at least bhai ke hello/hi ka reply toh kiya karo, naraaz ho kya bhai se ?

Comment: @Oreo:are bhai nahi aysa nahi hai. still issue is not solved?

Comment: bhaiya i have tagged you not to get answer, just to greet you good afternoon, anyways i am still looking for solution, not getting where is the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the

```
int i = start + 1; i <= end; i++
```

in the for loop to

```
int i = start + 1; i < end; i++
```

The `<=` validation adds an extra item.

Comment: I was suppose to get next 10 records on scroll and so on... But getting only first 10 records, please check my updated code above

Answer (score 0):

**Issue-1**: You have created a new instance of `mAdapter` before setting the `LayoutManager` for RecyclerView. Thereby the constructor code in the `DataAdapter` to add `ScrollListener` is not executed since `recyclerView.getLayoutManager()` returns `null`:

```
    if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager){
        // code to add ScrollListener is never executed
    }
```

**Fix**: First set the `LayoutManager` for the Recyclerview and then create the adapter like below:

```
    // use a linear layout manager
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new DataAdapter(temArray, mRecyclerView);
    // set the adapter object to the Recyclerview
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

**Issue-2:** You have used `temArray` to create `DataAdapter` but in `onLoadMore()` you are using the `studentList` to add/remove new items, since `studentList` is not binded with `mAdapter` your changes doesn't reflect in the UI.

**Fix:** Declare `temArray` as a class level variable and use `temArray` to manipulate the items.

```
 //class variable
 private ArrayList<Student> temArray = new ArrayList<Student>();

 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override public void run() {
              //   remove progress item
              temArray.remove(temArray.size() - 1);
              mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(temArray.size());
              //add items one by one
              int start = temArray.size();
              int end = start + 10;
              if(end<=studentList.size()){
                temArray.addAll(studentList.subList(start,end));
              }   
              mAdapter.setLoaded();
            }
          }, 2000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
    studentList.add(add data here) ;
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
}
```

Comment: i think you have to add data into list before notifyItemInserted.

Answer (score -1):

```
        mAdapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLoadMore() {
                        //add null , so the adapter will check view_type and show progress bar at bottom
                        studentList.add(null);
                        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size() - 1);

                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                //   remove progress item
                                studentList.remove(studentList.size() - 1);
                                mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(studentList.size());
                                //add items one by one
                                int start = studentList.size();
                                int end = start + 10;

                                for (int i = start + 1; i < end; i++) {
   // studentList.add();
                                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(studentList.size());
                                }
                                mAdapter.setLoaded();
                               //or you can add all at once but do not forget to call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }, 2000);
                    }
                });
```

ok so you inserted progress bar, and then you've removed it as well but you never inserted the next student to show...
something like studentList.add();

I hope that solved your problem... good luck..